# Code Igniter undefined variable users

Tags: codeigniter

I  need  help  on  this undefined  variable users:

[image]

i  have  set  the  variable  users in  the  User  Controller  as  follows:

```
class User extends Admin_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent :: __construct();

}

public function index()
{

    $this->data['users']=$this->user_m->get();
    $this->data['subview']='admin/user/index';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

and this  is the  code in  my view  file  index.php

```
<tbody>
<?php if(count($users)): foreach($users as $user): ?>      
<?php endforeach; ?>
<tr>

<td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->email); ?></td>          
<td><?php echo btn_edit('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id); ?></td>    
<td><?php echo btn_delete('admin/user/delete/' . $user->id);?></td>

</tr>    <?php else: ?>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">We could not find any users.</td>
</tr>

<?php endif; ?>

</tbody>
```

Comment: Please look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help to get useful answers

Comment: you just have to check `if (isset($users))` at the start of the view

Comment: please share output of `var_dump($this->user_m->get());`

Comment: When you load the subview within 'admin/_layout_main' are you passing a second parameter to it? If so you will be overwriting the vars that are currently in the view which would mean that there is no longer a `$users` var

Answer (score 0):

I solved  this  problem by:

1. Removing: `$this->data['users']=$this->user_m->get();` in  the  user `model(user_m)` and  creating  the  variable  in  the  view like  this:

   ```
   <?php 
   $users=$this->user_m->get();
   if(count($users)):foreach($users as $user):
   ?>
   ```